# how can i pass this javascript object in json?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, json, firefox

I am writing a firefox extension that uses pagemod with a list of regexes fetched from an url.

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var Request = require("request").Request;
var hosters = Request({
  url: "http://foo.bar/foo",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log(response.json.urls);
    var includeHosters = response.json.urls;
    pageMod.PageMod({
      include: includeHosters,
      contentScriptWhen: "start",
      contentScript: '',
      onAttach: function onAttach(worker) {
        // my code
      }
    });
  }
}).get();
```

the response from my server looks like this:

```
{
    "urls": [
        "/.*foo.*/",
        "/.*bar.*/"
    ]
}
```

The problem is that regexes only work when they are NOT enclosed by qutoation marks.

This works:

```
 include: [/.*foo.*/, /.*bar.*/],
```

Thie does not work:

```
 include: ["/.*foo.*/", "/.*bar.*/"],
```

Json requires strings to be enclosed in quotes.

On the server side i am working with PHP and have my regexes in an array like that:

```
<?
$regexes = array(".*foo.*",".*bar.*");
echo json_encode(array("urls" => $regexes));
```

This produces an output that firefox cannot work with.

How can I pass my regexes to the firefox extension?

Maby I need to do some str_repl stuff on the extension side?

But how? And how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON format doesn't define anything for regex, you have to build them after decoding.

Say you have this parsed array :

```
var strs = [".*foo.*", ".*bar.*"];
```

Then you can make a regex array like this :

```
var regexs = strs.map(function(v){ return new RegExp(v) });
```

If you prefer to send your regex strings with `/` as in

```
var strs = ["/.*foo.*/", "/.*bar.*/"];
```

Then you can do

```
var regexs = strs.map(function(v){ return new RegExp(v.slice(1,-1)) });
```

Comment: you are most awesome, please consider a drink and bed/breakfast for free if you happen to visit my city!

Comment: @TheSurrican I'll consider it if you fill the related "location" field in your profile ;)